# APIGEE - Regular Expression Not Working in Condition

Tags: regex, api, apigee

I am trying to use a condition to catch the case in which the query string of a request contains two or more parameters from a specific list. In such a case I wish to raise an error.

Of course, I can use many "and" and "or" clauses, but that will get very messy very quickly as the size of the list of parameters increases. So instead, I opted to use a regex to test for this.

As an example, if the list of parameters is [Bird,Dog,Horse], then any request who has two or more of these parameters in its query string should be matched.

The regular expression I am using is:

`/(.(Bird|Dog|Horse).){2}`

I tested in various regex testers and it works.

However, when I put the condition:

`request.querystring Matches "/(.(Bird|Dog|Horse).){2}"`

I never get a match.

Am I missing some specific APIGEE regex rules? Maybe the "{2}" is not supported in APIGEE? Thank you very much!!

Adam

Comment: Can you write the full of your condition

Comment: Of course, it is : <Step>
                    <Condition>(proxy.pathsuffix MatchesPath "/animals**") and (request.querystring Matches "/(.*(Bird|Dog|Hourse).*){2}")</Condition>
                    <Name>AssignMessage.ErrorType.Bad_Animal_Request</Name>
                </Step>

Comment: And give and example of your tested queryString and path that you have mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was I used "Matches" instead of "JavaRegex". 
I tried "JavaRegex" before, but it also didn't work - the second problem was that I have the "/" at the beginning, which is not needed if you use "JavaRegex".

https://community.apigee.com/questions/65080/regular-expression-not-working-in-condition.html?childToView=65113#answer-65113